# Python: How to retrieve POST parameters from HTML?

Tags: python, post

As far as I understand - there are two ways to pass information to HTML: GET and POST.
With certain actions/queries taken on website, GET will include these parameters of actions in URL which allows to then use resulting URL directly into, say, some database scraper script.
POST on the other hand is not as easy - it encodes the parameters and passes them without changing the URL. Therefore parameters are unknown to me and I don't know what query to write to get certain results.

Question: how to retrieve POST parameters via Python? 
Goal: write a script that allows to scrape a website in a same manner as if the website was GET-type.

Comment: The URL does change when you POST. You can change to the same URL perhaps, depending on how you handle the POST on the server side.

Comment: There is an encoded query that goes alongside with URL when using POST method. It looks very similar to GET. However - GET displays these parameters in the URL right away and the URL can be adjusted accordingly. POST hides these parameters therefore I don't know what to encode and pass to website query.

Comment: That's why you'd need to parse the form that instructed the browser what to post in the first place.

Comment: I feel that this might be step closer to the answer to my question.   So I suspect, source code might have some sort of form where I could retrieve these parameters?

Comment: Exactly; see the [HTML Form Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms) over on Mozilla Developer Network for an intro.